# How to show user comments in hierarchical fashion in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, recursion, asp.net-mvc-5, treeview, comments

I'm beginner in asp.net mvc.

I have a product model and I want implement user comments for any product. 
I want to show comments as tree for each level.

I use a recursive method  in my view to show comments and reply comment but
it cant show reply comments in third level .

The first level terms when replyId is empty displayed. Reply to  first comment are displayed first. But the answer of Previous reply does not show in the third level.

Please help me. Thank you so much.

This is my model

```
namespace Mvc_Shop.Models
{
public class Comment
{
    public Comment()
    {
        this.Children = new HashSet<Comment>();

    }
    public int Id { set; get; }

    public string Body { set; get; }

    public System.DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Reply { set; get; }

    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User_Id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int Product_Id { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("Product_Id")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
}
```

This is my view

```
@helper TreeView(IEnumerable<Mvc_Shop.Models.Comment> Comments)
{
foreach (var item in Comments)
{    
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body" id="Comment_@(item.Id)" style="padding: 3px;width: 100%;">
            <h4 class="media-heading">
                @item.User.UserName
                <label class="badge pull-left" style="font-weight: normal">@item.CommentDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm")</label>
            </h4>
            <div class="clearfix">
                @item.Body
            </div>
            <fieldset id="reply-cmnt-form_@(item.Id)" class="spr-form-review" style="display:none">
                <div class="spr-form-review-body">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Body, new { @class = "spr-form-label" })

                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment.Body, new { @class = "spr-form-input spr-form-input-text", id = "commentbody" + @item.Id })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Body)
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <a id="btn-hide-div_@(item.Id)" class="btn btn-xs pull-left btn-primary" style="clear: both; display:none" onclick="opencmntdiv(@item.Id);"> بستن</a>
            <a id="btn-send-div_@(item.Id)" class="btn btn-xs pull-left btn-primary" style="clear: both;float:right;display:none" onclick="ReplyComment(@item.Id);"> ارسال پاسخ</a>
            <a id="btn-show-div_@(item.Id)" class="btn btn-xs pull-left btn-primary" style="clear: both" onclick="opencmntdiv(@item.Id);"> پاسخ</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="clearfix" />
    if (item.Children.Any())
    {          
        @TreeView(item.Children)    
    }
}
}                              

@TreeView(Model.Comments)
```

and this is my action

```
public ActionResult ShowProducts(string ProductName)
{
        _dbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ShopContext>();
        var model = new UserCommentViewModel();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductName))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            model.Products = blproduct.Where(p => p.Name.Trim() == ProductName.Trim()).ToList();
            model.Comments = (from u1 in _dbContext.Users
                              join u2 in _dbContext.Comments
                                  on u1.Id equals u2.User.Id
                              where u2.ReplyId == null
                              select new {
                                  Id = u2.Id, Body = u2.Body, CommentDate = u2.CommentDate, User = u1,Children = u2.Children
                              }).ToList().Select(x => new Comment
                              { 
                                  Id = x.Id, Body = x.Body, CommentDate = x.CommentDate, User = x.User,Children = x.Children
                              }).ToList();

            if (model != null)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I solve my question. I remove "where u2.replyId== null" in my query .